# Modify c++ code that finds the subarray with the maximum sub less than or equal to given sum

Tags: c++, vector, sum, c++17, sub-array

I would like to modify a function responsible for writing the subarray (well, in this case a vector) out to the console with the highest sum less than or equal to a given sum. What I would like change is that the function should be able to use the same element multiple times when calculating the sum.

For example: if the given vector is `{30, 60}` and the desired sum is `135` it would right now write `60, 30` out but what I would like it to do is write either `60, 60`, `60, 30, 30` or `30, 30, 30, 30` in any order, because the elements in the given vector should be reusable while calculating the sum.

Here is the function in it's current form:

```cpp
void findMaxSubarraySum(std::vector<int> arr, int sum)
{
    int curr_sum = arr[0], max_sum = 0, start = 0;
    std::vector<int> maxArr, currArr;

    currArr.push_back(arr[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {

        if (max_sum <= curr_sum) {
            max_sum = curr_sum;
            maxArr = currArr;
        }

        while (curr_sum + arr[i] > sum && start < i) {
            curr_sum -= arr[start];
            currArr.erase(std::remove(currArr.begin(), currArr.end(), arr[start]), currArr.end());
            start++;
        }

        curr_sum += arr[i];
        currArr.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    if (curr_sum <= sum) {
        max_sum = curr_sum;
        maxArr = currArr;
    }

    for (int element : maxArr) {
        std::cout << element << ", ";
    }
}
```

I've tried adding adding each element of the vector to itself `sum / element` times by adding this code to start of the function:

```cpp
for (int element : arr) {
    int n = sum / element;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        arr.push_back(element);
    }
}
```

but the problem with this is that it's not just very inefficient, but it also doesn't work, because the program just exits without outputing anything.

How could I modify this function (or just write one that works differently) that does this?

Comment: You should be working this out on paper first before a single line of code has been written.  Then once you work this out, then write the program that fits what you've written down.  Musing over already written code that obviously is inefficient or "doesn't work" is not going to be helpful.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, I tried, but so far none of my previous plans really worked out and this is the closest I've gotten. My original idea was to try recursion but I couldn't figure out how I could check if what I got is bigger than some previous array, because what I did is went through all possibilities and each time the first element of the checked possibility was changed a new line of recursion started and I couldn't figure out how to check if the end result here is better than in the previous line of recursion.

Comment: The first step is figuring out how to describe the problem. You're not really asking for sub-arrays, you're asking for _every combination of array elements with replacement, summing to at most M_. (Replacement just means you replace each chosen element so it can be reused).

Comment: Yes that is right, but in my current code it's a subarray, but it doesn't really make a difference as all of it's elements are a being added manually when certain conditions are met and nothing is stopping me from adding something that would change it's subarray nature. @Useless

Comment: You're talking about the organization of the data, which is specific to your code. I'm talking about what these operations are called in general, so you can find existing reference material, instead of trying to reinvent combinatorics from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

> Modify c++ code that finds the subarray with the maximum sub less than or equal to given sum

Don't, just write it from scratch. Trying to mutate one algorithm into a different one is hard, even in the case where you fully understand both. Since you don't sound like you understand how the new one is actually supposed to act, this is never likely to work.

> ... writing the subarray ... out to the console ...

A word of advice: don't mix I/O into your algorithms. It's much easier to test & debug a pure function that just takes the input and returns the result.

Writing a function to call that and then print the result is also easy. At least, assuming you can return a whole container.

For sequences that are either infinite or impractically large, you really want something like a Python generator, which is a little harder to write in C++ (but do the easiest possible thing first and test with small inputs, you can worry about large ones later if it becomes a problem).

> ...  the highest sum less than or equal to a given sum. What I would like change is that the function should be able to use the same element multiple times when calculating the sum.

The first step is figuring out how to describe the problem. You're not really asking for sub-arrays, you're asking for *every combination of array elements with replacement, summing to at most M*. (Replacement just means you replace each chosen element so it can be reused).

Let's give these things names, so you want to produce

> *every combination C from a set of length N such that sum(C) <= Max*

You can read up on how this sort of stuff (*permutations*, *combinations* etc.) are normally done, but there's a trick to prune your computation when you want to limit the sum of your combination<sub>with-replacement</sub>:

1. sort the input so the largest element is first
2. walk past anything larger than `Max`, because we know we can't ever use it
3. now we have a slightly simpler function on some subset of our sorted vector (it could be the whole thing, but at least we know that every element is usable)

And finally you can start to classify your outputs. For example you should have each individual element as a sequence of length one (since we filtered out anything too large in step 2). You should have a 2-element sequence with two of the same element if `e*e <= Max`, and so on. You can write each of these cases out explicitly to start with, and then refactor them into (nested) loops when you see how they work.